# Connect problem with MSDAORA with Oracle 18 Client

Tags: c#, oracle18c

I have a Windows Form C# project and want to connect with an oracle 18 client to the database with the "MSDAORA.1" Provider.

Before I installed Oracle 18 client, I used Oracle 11 Client. With this client, the connection was created. 
Is it not possible to get a connection with Oracle 18 client? Or what can be the problem?

I get the error message that the provider is not installed. But the provider is installed.

Here my code:

OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.1;User ID=user;password=pw;Data Source = db; Persist Security Info = False");

connect.Open();

Best regards
Thomas

Comment: Do you receive an error, if so which one?

Comment: I get the error message that the provider is not installed. But the provider is installed.

Comment: Can you try a "TNSPING yourDbName" to verify your client is properly setup? (cf. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/netag/testing-connections.html#GUID-9A550EEC-5736-46B4-B10E-55849B01A4D0 )

Comment: TSNPING ist working without an error!

Comment: It's been a long time I used Oracle, but the ".1" in your connectionstring looks strange? Shouldn't it be just "Provider=MSDAORA;User ID=user;password=pw;Data Source = db; Persist Security Info = False" ?  (cf. https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle-msdaora)

Comment: I recall that MSDORA doesn't work with Windows 10.  are you (were you!) trying to use windows 10?  We changed ours out for OraOLEDB.Oracle.